# Youtube video upload/download along with captions/ transcript files

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, youtube

I am aware of the [youtube api for .net](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083164/downloading-video-from-youtube).

The problem that I am facing is that I want to upload youtube video with captions or more importantly a **transcript file** and if download them as well. Does anybody know how to do this in C# (silverlight) ?

Comment: Did you tried _new_ ***YouTube Data API (v3)*** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Developers Guide: Data API Protocol – Captions](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions.html)

For the C# bit, it's just writing a bit of HTTP.

Comment: `The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014`. Any sample using ***YouTube Data API (v3)*** ?